# Rust framework without "object cannot be sent between threads safely"

Tags: web-development, framework, rust

Is there (preferably asynchronous) Rust web framework without being prone to errors like

> object/future cannot be sent between threads safely

?

Comment: probably not, not one that is safe at least

Comment: The solution of the real problem is to use `tokio::sync::Mutex` instread of `std::async::Mutex`,